# How to limit GetFiles to get all paths created after a certain date?

Tags: vb.net

I'm a beginner in VB and I'm throwing together a quick tool to pull data out of excel sheets into an SQL server.

The actual opening/manipulation of the excel files I can do, but I would like to limit the files I'm dealing with based on the created date, but I'm struggling with googling a solution

So in order to get all of the paths, I'm simply using:

```
Dim fname As String

For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(pathtoscan)
fname = Path.GetFileName(file)
```

Which works fine to get everything (writing to the SQL server table as I go), but of course the above means getting every single path, where as I'd like to "optimise" it by only getting paths created after a certain defined date.

Is this doable, or would it simply be a matter of filtering after grabbing all paths anyway, and thus mean no better "performance"?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ and [`File.GetCreationTime`:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Dim relevantFiles = From f In Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathtoscan)
                    Where File.GetCreationTime(f) > yourDate

For Each file As String In relevantFiles 
    ' ... '
Next
```

Also use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`. The latter returns an array of all files before you start filtering them. The former returns one after the other.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly.  Out of curiosity, is there a variant of this if looking at directories rather than files, i.e.    For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(pathtoscan) ?